# What is the moving line at the top of vscode, and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently VSCode is showing an animated line, that moves constantly from the left to the right. The movement is distracting when I am trying to code.

**What is the line, and how can I disable it?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it's "loading" something in the background.

Display the Ouptut console <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> (or: View > Output) and on the right, in a selectable list, check the different tasks or logs to see what process is still pending.

Sometimes it's a plugin which is stuck, or a wrong configuration of your project.

It could also simply be a bug in VSCode.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Alas/thanksfully the behavior fixed itself after restarted VScode, but will try this if it happens agin.